# Setting up CakePHP shared hosting

Tags: php, cakephp, directory-structure

I am following this doc for installing CakePHP on a shared hosting host: http://book.cakephp.org/view/915/Advanced-Installation

I can't figure out where to install the cakephp files on my server.

Right now I have:

```
/public_html
.../cake
....../console
....../config
....../scripts
....../tests
.../app
....../models
....../views
....../controllers
....../and so on...
.../blog( MY SITE )
....../css
....../img
....../files
....../js
......(.htacess) file
......index.php
.../libs
....../all the libs files
```

Is this the recommended set up?  Or should I have the following directory (all came in the CakePHP install) in the root folder(dir above public_html, basically '/home/myusername/')?

```
/cake
/app
/libs
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the correct settup.  But I am totally lost with the next part(editing all of the .htacess). http://book.cakephp.org/view/917/Apache-and-mod_rewrite-and-htaccess

I have a .htaccess in public_html, in /app and /blog

Comment: This is so frustrating. I went through the whole tut and now when I goto my .org site all I see is a blank page.  Before I installed cake php it just showed the folders in my public_html dir

Answer (score 4):

It does't really matter how exactly you do it, as long as it works. *But*, you should keep the "internal" files out of the public web root. Say your host gives you access to this kind of directory structure:

```
/camman
    /public_html
```

The `public_html` folder is set as the web root, anything in there is exposed to the web. You *can* dump all your cake files in there and let rewriting take care of it, but it's better to only expose Cake's `/app/webroot` there, which is the only folder containing public files (CSS and so forth). The rest of the files should be kept above the web root like so:

```
/camman
    /myapp
        /app
        /cake
    /public_html
        .htaccess
        /css
        /img
        index.php
        ...
```

Only the contents of the `/app/webroot` folder go into the `public_html` directory, the rest is placed somewhere private. That means you need to update the paths defined in `/app/webroot/index.php`. This setup is better since files in `/app` contain critical information like passwords, which you do not want publicly exposed in case of a server failure.